# convolution vs correlation?

Tags: convolution, correlation

What is difference between convolution and correlation?In simple words or in a nut shell?

As far as i am able to study is that Convolution is a mathematical operation used to express the relation between input and output of an LTI system. It relates input, output and impulse response of an LTI system while Correlation is a measure of similarity between two signals

Comment: You got it very well, in a nutshell! That's exactly what they are. There are some further connection between them, but what you said is exactly to the point!

Comment: In a system in which place value is valued,( like the decimal number system ), convolution is the actual way of multiplication to be used to obtain the product of two entities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convolution:

$$ y(t) = h(t) \circledast x(t) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(u) \, x(t-u) \ \mathrm{d}u $$

Cross Correlation:

$$ R_{xy}(t) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} y(u) \, x(t+u) \ \mathrm{d}u $$

The difference between the two is effectively the sign on $u$ in $x(t-u)$ in the integral.  That correlation is like convolution but with one of the signals flipped left to right is essentially the basis of the **Matched Filter**.

Comment: missed conjugate in the second equation

Comment: @robert Do you mean,in convolution,we always have sign with u,that is opposite sign to the sign on u in correlation?

Comment: @robert Do you mean ,we will always have - sign,with u in convolution and positive sign with u in correlation?or vice versa also possible?

Comment: @robert Actually convolution is the flipped one, not the correlation. Correlation is the multiplication of the conjugated signal with a delayed( or advanced ) version of the second signal

Comment: @engr 
if we are able to find a function $x(t)$ 
where $x(t) = {u^*}(-t) $ then

\begin{equation}
x(t) \ast v(t) = u(t) \otimes v(t)
\end{equation}

Comment: @abhilash what you are trying to demonstrate in your last comment is that when x(t)=u(-t), convolution and correlation will be equal/same?? and your equation ??what idea is conveyed by your equation? is it also says that when x(t)=u(-t), convolution and correlation will be equal/same

Comment: @abhilash what do you intend by * ,by which you raised u,when already you have changed(made negative)sign of time in u(t)??

Comment: The $*$ is the complex conjugation operator.  $(a + j b)^* = a - j b$.

Comment: @abhilash , you are correct.  i was assuming real $x(t)$, $y(t)$, and $h(t)$ and real $t$ and $u$ in all cases.

Comment: *"Do you mean,in convolution,we always have sign with $u$,that is opposite sign to the sign on $u$ in correlation?"*  yes @engr i do mean that.  this is why the impulse response of a matched filter resembles the signal you're trying to detect, but it's flipped left-to-right.